# How are 连绵词 used in modern Chinese?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, vocabulary

A concise definition of 连绵词 I found is

> an alliterative and echotic biome

e.g. ：

- 窈窕
- 徘徊
- 孜孜

Is this group perceived as sth. distinctive with unique rules how or under which circumstances to use them? 
How are they perceived in terms of aesthetics, e.g. do they convey a poetic or archaic connotation?

Comment: http://baike.baidu.com/view/313939.htm ２-syllable morpheme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [聯綿詞](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%81%AF%E7%B6%BF%E8%A9%9E)

聯綿詞 is a terminology in Chinese phonology. They are still functional 詞(compound words).

> do they convey a poetic or archaic connotation?

Some 聯綿詞 adjective and verb do sound poetic or archaic (e.g 玲瓏, 翩翩, 叮嚀,  拮据).

Some 聯綿詞 adjective and verb had become common day-to-day words (e.g. 荒唐, 嘮叨, 累贅, 凌厲)

Almost all 聯綿詞 noun are common day-to-day words (e.g. 琵琶, 橄欖, 鞦韆, 蝴蝶)